# Try getservbyport to display mongod service in python3

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, sockets

I am learning socket programming in python3 lately. Here is one little bothering question when I try **getservbyport** method to display the service name of mongod.

Here is my code:

```
import socket
print(socket.getservbyport(80))   # 'http' returns as expected
print(socket.getservbyport(3306))   # 'mysql' returns as expected
print(socket.getservbyport(27017))   # OSError: port/proto not found
```

To be confirmed, the mongod is running on port 27017 in another terminal window at the same time.

```
MongoDB starting : pid=18791 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=xxx
```

So why `print(socket.getservbyport(27017))` not return something like mongod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `socket.getservbyport()` function translates port numbers to well-known services that are usually registered with IANA (The Internet Assigned Number Authority). On a UNIX-like system you will typically find the local list of known services in a plain text file: `/etc/services`.

The [`getservbyport`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyport) mapping is only a convenience lookup for what service might *reasonably* be expected to be listening to a given port. This does not check if there is currently a service actively listening, or if a listening service is actually the expected service.

> So why `print(socket.getservbyport(27017))` not return something like mongod?

This means that your `/etc/services` file (or equivalent) does not have an entry associating port 27017 with `mongod`. More specifically, port 27017 is currently not officially associated with `mongod` on the [IANA protocol port number registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=27017).

It is possible to add local entries to your `/etc/services` file, however any changes are likely to be overwritten in a future O/S update.

For example, if you edit `/etc/services` and add an entry for `mongod` you should see this returned as the result of your Python  `socket.getservbyport(27017)` call:

```
mongod          27017/tcp   # MongoDB
```

> To be confirmed, the mongod is running on port 27017 in another terminal window at the same time.

For more comprehensive port mapping (including detection of the running service listening on a port) I would consider using [`python-nmap`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap). Nmap includes an [`nmap-services`](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-services) file with additional common port associations including several for MongoDB (i.e. those listed in the [Default MongoDB Port](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/) section of the MongoDB manual). Nmap only scans a subset of ports and services by default, so you will have to check the Nmap documentation for the right combination of options to provide based on the range of ports and services you'd like to scan.